# Synchronize observables for http calls

Tags: angular, rxjs, angular2-services, angular2-observables, reactive

I have a delete method that calls odata delete service as below:

```
deleteValues = (key) => {
    return new Promise((resolve, reject) => {
        ...

        this._referenceDataService.deleteReferenceData(etag, url).subscribe(
            data => {
                resolve(data);
            },
            error => {
                this._notificationService.displayNotification(NotificationTypeEnum.Error, JSON.parse(error._body).error.message.value);
                reject(error);
            },
            () => {
                this._notificationService.displayNotification(NotificationTypeEnum.Success, "Data deleted successfully.");
            }
        );
    });
}
```

Here `deleteReferenceData` method returns an observable from the http service of Angular2.

For a data grid, if I delete 3 rows, then the method is called 3 times for individual rows.

I want a behavior where even if the method `deleteValues` is called 3 times one after another, the service calls for 2 and 3 rows should be made only when the service call for 1 is completed.

Answer (score 0):

You could use a queue up front to queue subsequent service calls, and then just pop them off as each one completes.

It could look like something...

```
private isDeleting;
private deleteValuesQueue;

deleteValues = (key) => {
   this.deleteValuesQueue.unshift(key);
   if(!isDeleting) this.runDeleteValues(this.deleteValuesQueue.pop());
}

runDeleteValues = (key) => {
   this.isDeleting = true;
   // your actual delete function goes here...

   // when the promise resolves or rejects and you want to execute the next item off the queue do
   if(deleteValuesQueue.length > 0) this.runDeleteValues(this.deleteValuesQueue.pop());
   else this.isDeleting = false;
}
```

So what's going on here is you're keeping track of the queue of keys you want to delete, and if you're currently deleting something. This is managed in deletedValues() which you call from your components.

When it's called, if you're not running anything, go ahead and send it to the real delete. Elsewise throw it in the queue. Now when you're running a real delete, at the end, check if there's anything in the queue and run those... or say you're done deleting and allow deleteValues to call the next one as it comes in.